# How to check a type of column values in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I can check column types using `df.dtypes`, where `df` is pandas DataFrame. However, my question is a bit different. I have the following DataFrame:

```
col1 col2
0    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
1    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
2    <class 'float'>
3    NaN
4    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

The `df["col2"].dtypes` returns `object`.

I need to create a new column `is_timestamp` that would check if `col2` value is pandas timestamp. For testing, I tried this code:

```
isinstance(df_viz["col2"][0], pd._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp)
```

But it returns `False`.

The expected output:

```
col1 col2                                                 col3
0    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>   Yes
1    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>   Yes
2    <class 'float'>                                      No
3    NaN                                                  No
4    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>   Yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
df_viz['col3']=(df_viz.col2.transform(lambda x:
  np.where(x==pd._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp,'Yes','No')))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check for each row like this

```
df['check_datetime'] = [type(val) == datetime.datetime for val in df['datime_field']]
```

I'm not sure about your type you can find your type by (type(val)) and place them into code

if you want 'YES' and 'NO'

can using

```
df['my_col'] = np.where(df['my_col'] is True,"YES","NO)
```

[my try code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nxGA.png)